# Process started with subprocess module goes to sleep

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a process that is started via `subprocess.Popen()` which is meant to run indefinitely.  The problem i was having was that the process seemed to stop running after about 20 seconds.  Sure enough when i check `top`, it shows that the process is going to sleep.  When i run the command manually this doesn't happen.

Anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

This is the subprocess call:

```
aireplay = subprocess.Popen('aireplay-ng -3 -b ' + target.mac + ' ' + interface, 
                            shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = DN)

time.sleep(5)
starttime = time.time()
ivs = 0
second = False
print 'Sending deauth to generate arps...'
send_deauth(target)

while time.time() - starttime < 1200:
    targets = parsecsvfile('crackattempt')
    print 'Captured ' + str(ivs) + ' ivs.'
    print aireplay.poll()
    if len(targets[0]) > 0:
        target = targets[0][0]
        if ivs > 20000:
            break
        else :
            ivs = int(target.ivs)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: People will be able to help you if you show some code.

Comment: More information, please, about what this process is doing. What's the last thing it does before going to sleep? Is it consistently 20 seconds? Consistently up to a certain point in the code? Consistently until it attempts to use a particular resource, data structure, etc.? Is the process a C program, another bit of Python, or what? Etc.

Comment: Sorry i added the subprocess call above.  The process (airmon-ng) performs an arp replay attack on a router, ie it sends and receives data back and forth through the network card.  It generally happens after 10 - 30 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are piping the output of the subprocess.  It will sleep when its buffer is full - did you remember to read stdout from the subprocess?

You could use the `communicate` method if you don't mind it blocking, or read from the `stdout` file descriptor, or maybe send the stdout to /dev/null since you don't seem to be using it.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I didn't know it slept when the buffer was full.  I just sent the stdout to /dev/null and it worked!